# "Unexpected End of Input" Error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am hitting a small block when running a javascript(from the [CSS Tricks Demos](http://css-tricks.com/downloads)) where I get a "Unexpected end of input" error. here's the code.

```
function UpdateTableHeaders() {
$(".persist-area").each(function() {

       var el             = $(this),
           offset         = el.offset(),
           scrollTop      = $(window).scrollTop(),
           floatingHeader = $(".floatingHeader", this)

       if ((scrollTop > offset.top) && (scrollTop < offset.top + el.height())) {
           floatingHeader.css({
            "visibility": "visible"
           });
       } else {
           floatingHeader.css({
            "visibility": "hidden"
           });      
       };
   });
}

// DOM Ready      
$(function() {

   var clonedHeaderRow;

   $(".persist-area").each(function() {
       clonedHeaderRow = $(".persist-header", this);
       clonedHeaderRow
         .before(clonedHeaderRow.clone())
         .css("width", clonedHeaderRow.width())
         .addClass("floatingHeader");

   });

   $(window)
    .scroll(UpdateTableHeaders)
    .trigger("scroll");
```

Can someone please help me?

Comment: `$(function() {` is opened but is never closed, `});` after `.trigger("scroll");`

Comment: Like @Ohgodwhy says, you just need to add `});` at the end of your file.

Comment: Thanks guys. Another day, another asinine error.

Comment: "Unexpected End of Input" errors show up when you opened something (round brackets, curly brackets, strings) that needed to be closed and you don't. The parsing/interpreter tool then complains it finds the end of the input unexpectedly before what was supposed to be closed was closed.

Comment: In the future, use a JS IDE or run it through JSLint, http://www.jslint.com

Comment: Also, you need a semicolon at the end of `floatingHeader = $(".floatingHeader", this)`

Comment: @Jacedc: No, semicolons to mark the end of an expressions are optional.